# Maintaining order of operations when evaluating a simple math expression without parentheses

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, operator-precedence

I am creating a calculator program in C which takes up to 5 numbers and 4 operations and then calculates the answer as a way to better learn the language. I have almost everything working properly except that it doesn't follow order of operations yet. The only way that I have been able to think of to make it do this would be to somehow sort the operations and numbers at the same time by moving multiplication and division statements to the front of the array, and addition and subtraction statements to the back. I have absolutely no idea how to go about this however and I think that it's a pretty safe assumption that there is a better, more efficient way to accomplish this task. Does anyone who has more experience in C know how one might go about this?

Here is my code at the moment:

```
/* A calculator that accepts up to 5 numbers and performs
multiple mathematical operations on the given numbers. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Creating functions for each of
the basic mathematical operators */

double add(double x, double y) {
    /* Add variables x and y */
    return x + y;
}

double subtract(double x, double y) {
    /* Subtract variables x and y */
    return x - y;
}

double multiply(double x, double y) {
    /* Multiply variables x and y */
    return x * y;
}

double divide(double x, double y) {
    /* Divide variables x and y */
    return x / y;
}

/* "operation" typedef to point
to the above operator functions */
typedef double (*operation)(double, double);

int main() {
    double nums[5];
    char operator;
    operation operators[5];    // operator functions pointer array
    double result;
    int i = 0;    // index variable to be used for iteration

    printf("\n ################################\n");
    printf(" ########## Calculator ##########\n");
    printf(" ################################\n\n");
    printf(" You may enter up to 5 numbers in you calculation.\n");
    printf(" If you wish to enter fewer than 5 numbers, type an \"=\" as the operator after your final number.\n\n");

    while (i < 5) {
        // Getting the user's input
        printf(" Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &nums[i]);
        if (i == 4) {
            operators[i] = NULL;    // Sets the final operator to NULL
        } else {
            printf(" Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, or =): ");
            scanf(" %c", &operator);

            /* Switch statement to decide which function to run on
            the given numbers on each iteration through the loop */
            switch(operator) {
                case '+' :
                    operators[i] = add;
                    break;
                case '-' :
                    operators[i] = subtract;
                    break;
                case '*' :
                    operators[i] = multiply;
                    break;
                case '/' :
                    operators[i] = divide;
                    break;
                default :
                    operators[i] = NULL;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (!operators[i]) break;    // Breaks out of the loop if the current operator is NULL
        i++;    // Increments the index variable up by 1
    }


    result = nums[0];
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (operators[i - 1]) {
            result = operators[i - 1](result, nums[i]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Printing out the answer rounded to 2 decimal points
    printf("Result: %.2f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have functions for each operation at the top and a while loop that takes a number and an operator and inserts the appropriate function into an array using a switch statement. Afterwards, I have a `for` loop that goes through the arrays and performs the operations in the order that they have been entered. This is what is causing the answer to not be technically correct because it performs each operation on the answer that resulted from the last go through the for loop. This is why I wish to sort the operations in the array. If I could put all of the operations and numbers in the correct order before all of the calculations happen, then it will follow order of operations and give the correct answer.

Here is a sample of the output of my current program:

```
################################
########## Calculator ##########
################################

You may enter up to 5 numbers in you calculation.
If you wish to enter fewer than 5 numbers, type an "=" as the operator after your final number.

Enter a number: 3
Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, or =): +
Enter a number: 6
Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, or =): -
Enter a number: 7
Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, or =): *
Enter a number: 3
Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, or =): /
Enter a number: 2
Result: 3.00
[Finished in 21.57s]
```

And here is a sample of what I would like it to come up with:

```
################################
########## Calculator ##########
################################

You may enter up to 5 numbers in you calculation.
If you wish to enter fewer than 5 numbers, type an "=" as the operator after your final number.

Enter a number: 3
Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, or =): +
Enter a number: 6
Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, or =): -
Enter a number: 7
Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, or =): *
Enter a number: 3
Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, or =): /
Enter a number: 2
Result: -1.50
[Finished in 21.57s]
```

Is there any way that anybody can think of to accomplish this?

Comment: You might consider converting infix notation to reverse polish, using a stack.

Comment: Could you give an example of how I might do that? I am still pretty new to C and I don't know how that would work yet.

Comment: https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/master/c/calc.c

Comment: It might be out of scope for your problem because it's moderately complex, but there are YouTube videos and articles that can explain this particular approach to implementing a calculator.

Comment: If you aren't supporting parens, iterate and compute all the high-precedence ops, then make a second pass and compute all the low-precedence ops. If parens are involved, maybe try the shunting yard algorithm. Or just run `bc` as a subprocess ;-)

Comment: @ggorlen could you make an answer with an example of that? That sounds like pretty much what I would like to do but I am still not sure of how I would do it. I am not supporting parens so I would just be using the first method. P.S. I would use bc except that that kinda feels like cheating since I wouldn't be learning how to properly do this in C.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't supporting parentheses in your expressions, the problem is greatly simplified and you can use two passes over the input expression to evaluate it. The guarantee here is that the expression tree is never more than 2 levels deep. The first pass is responsible for handling the higher precedence operations (multiply, divide) and ensuring these are done with correct sign. The second pass just applies addition and subtraction to whatever remains.

I assume the parameter can be mutated, that the expression was parsed and validated correctly, application crashes on division by zero, doesn't handle overflow, uses ints for simplicity, etc, so consider this just a quick and dirty proof-of-concept to show the two-pass expression evaluation technique.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV};
int _add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
int _sub(int a, int b) {return a - b;}
int _mul(int a, int b) {return a * b;}
int _div(int a, int b) {return a / b;}
int (*ops[4])(int x, int y) = {_add, _sub, _mul, _div};

int eval_math_expr_without_parens(int len, int *e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 2; i += 2) {
        if (e[i+1] == SUB) {
            e[i+1] = ADD;
            e[i+2] *= -1;
        }

        if (e[i+1] == MUL || e[i+1] == DIV) {
            e[i+2] = ops[e[i+1]](e[i], e[i+2]);
            e[i+1] = ADD;
            e[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len - 2; i += 2) {
        e[i+2] = ops[e[i+1]](e[i], e[i+2]);
    }

    return len ? e[len-1] : 0;
}

int main() {
    int lens[] = {3, 3, 5, 5, 9, 11, 11};
    int exprs[][13] = {
        {2, MUL, 5},
        {2, ADD, 5},
        {2, MUL, 5, ADD, 3},
        {2, SUB, 5, MUL, 3},
        {2, ADD, 5, MUL, 3, MUL, 2, SUB, 3},
        {20, DIV, 5, ADD, 3, MUL, 2, SUB, 3, MUL, 4},
        {20, SUB, 5, SUB, 3, SUB, 4, MUL, 2, SUB, 3, MUL, 4},
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lens[i]; j++) {
            if (j % 2) {
                printf("%c", "+-*/"[exprs[i][j]]);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d", exprs[i][j]);
            }
        }
    
        printf("=%d\n", eval_math_expr_without_parens(lens[i], exprs[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Quick test:

```
$ ./a.out
2*5=10
2+5=7
2*5+3=13
2-5*3=-13
2+5*3*2-3=29
20/5+3*2-3*4=-2
20-5-3-4*2-3=1
$ ./a.out | awk -F '=' '{print $1}' | bc
10
7
13
-13
29
-2
1
```

If you do need to support parens, then you have arbitrary depth to the tree and this strategy won't help. It's a solved problem, of course, so check out the [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) or just run `bc` as a subprocess and capture the result (slow but easy).